# Multiple Datatriggers overwrite

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

```
<Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Result.IsRejected}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Result.RilibakViolation}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Result.RilibakViolation}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ControlsForegroundColor}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Result.IsViolated}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Result.IsViolated}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ControlsForegroundColor}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Result.ResultIncluded}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="IndianRed"/>
        </DataTrigger>

    </Style.Triggers>
```

I have this code where i tried to change the Foreground color according to different properties of that Result object. My problem is that only the last 3 work and IsRejected or RilibakViolation do not work. Ex: even if the first one is true it will be not displayed green. Is there another approach for this code to make it works in all this cases?

Comment: Which states of `Result` have you tested? All your triggers change the `Foreground`, so the latest trigger wins.

Answer (score 0):

A good way will be to create a MultiConverter and pass all the necessary properties (IsRejected, RilibakViolation, IsViolated etc.). The converter will receive the parameters and than decide which color to return.

In that way, each time a property in the model is changed, the converter is activated and the Foreground is changed accordingly.